# Wordpress MultiSite Install - One Page returning Server 500 Error

Tags: wordpress

I have an install of Wordpress 3.0 with Multisite install setup. It has been working for ages but all of a sudden 1 page on one of the sites has started returning a server 500 error. On all the other sites everything is fine, including sites that use the same page???

Does anyone have any ideas?

[Page with error](http://alanbrandt.dk/portefolje/) 
[Same page on another site](http://alanbrandt.com/portfolio)

Any ideas appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Appears that the default "post page" was no longer set in the WP "Settings > Reading" section...

Once the correct page was selected from the dropdown everthing returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

i also get same error and resolved by this before this backup ur htaccess file
just delete all data from ur .htaccess and copy past code which u will get from "Network Setup"